# Error NullPointerException when running an altered version of an Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse, import

I have this Android program running well, called TestePHP2 (name of main class), package  com.testedeacesso.www. It is stable and runs perfectly.

I've cloned this project's folder to start developing an upgrade to it. I called it TesteTempo01, after importing it to Eclipse - option 'from existing project' (yes, I used the refractor to change the class name and I checked 'update references'). I modified this program's main class as I mentioned before and added some code to it, but I kept the package name the same, as well as other classes from the program.

Whe I try to run this program, though, I got a 'can't find main activity' error. After searching through my code, I found out that on the manifest there was a reference to the TestePHP2 that I hadn't changed before. for reference, this was the line on the Android Manifest XML:

```
> <activity android:name="com.testedeacesso2.www.TesteTempo01"
>                   android:label="@string/app_name">
```

After this, I keep getting a NullPointerException because the class can't find the main class! I've searched through the whole code but I found no other references to the old class. Have I forgotten something? Do I need to alter something else to change this class' name? Or the import will only work with the original class names?

Answer (score 0):

You said the package was 'com.testedeacesso.www', but when you reference the class, its 'com.testedeacesso2.www'.  I'm guessing you have a problem with class/package references.

Comment: You are right, but now that you mention it, I didn't change the package name, so com.testedeacesso2.www is the right name - both for the package that works and this new one.

One thing that called my attention was that the R class of my program is in a totally different package - com.testepaginaphp.www. Can this be interfering with this problem somehow?

Comment: Absolutely.  We've had to change the package name on an app before.  It generates 'R' in a different package.  You need to make sure your apps import statements reflect that or they won't compile.  Other than that, though, it shouldn't cause much trouble.